# Calling a command line program

Tags: command-line, wolfram-mathematica

I have a executable that when double clicked opens in a command line window.[image]

Now there is a input file (i.e named "sphere_15000.inp") in the same directory where the executable apame_win64.exe is  located. So we can inter the file name in the command line.
[image]

The question is how this can be done from mathematica front end? With the `RunThrough` command I tried to do it with no avail.

```
RunThrough["Executable Location", "sphere_15000"]
```

Do I need to put this file location in my Windows 7 environment path variable? Hope for some suggestion in this regard.

**UPDATE**

Found a solution to my problem.

1. First set the Mathematica directory to the folder where the executable is located.

   path="C:\Users\FlowCrusher\Desktop\CUSP solver\Apame_build_2011_01_09\solver";
   SetDirectory[path];
2. Then use the following style of input.

   Run["\"\"apame_win64.exe\" \"input\"\""]

Here "apame_win64.exe" is the executable one want to run and "input" is the input file for the executable. This solves the problem. But a new item in the wishlist.

**Is there a way to hide the console window in the background?**

Here is how it looks on my screen.
[image]

As Chris suggested if we use minimized console in the Run command we get a minimized window but the program does not execute.

[image]

I hope that a solution exists.

BR

Comment: One problem with `Run` (and the same should hold for `RunThrough`, which is implemented on top of `Run`) for Windows is that it won't treat correctly directories which contain spaces in them (actually, this is more a problem of the underlying Windows shell). I've run into this issue more than once, may be it is this problem you are having too. The general way out is to wrap the path in quotation marks. Relevant MathGroup thread: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/8c8a5c77ec25240c

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeonidShifrin. The link was a lot of help.

Comment: @ Plato, try `Run["start /min \"\"apame_win64.exe\" \"input\"\""]` to run minimised, or even `Run["cmd /c start /min \"\"apame_win64.exe\" \"input\"\""]` - ref: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000932.htm

Comment: @ChrisDegnen It is not working in that case. The console is coming for a second and minimizing with out the external program being executed.

Comment: @PlatoManiac With regards to your second question, another useful thread comes to mind: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/dc7f73136e54b68f . It is quite dated though - can't comment on the current state of affairs. But chances are that, regarding the popping window problem, you will be better off writing a shell Mathematica script calling your program - which is easy in M8 due to the improved scripting capabilities, or, making the answer of Rolf Mertig work on Win7.

Comment: @ Plato - The problem seems to be the quotes. Are you sure you need them all.  You don't have any spaces in the filenames. See if this works: `Run["start /min apame_win64 input"]`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thanks a lot. The job is done with `Run["start /min apame_win64 input"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you might put the folder of you executable into the Path variable, or provide the full path name.

However, RunThrough seems to have been superseeded (on Windows) by 
Import["!command ","Text"], which will execute command and read the comaand line output into Matheamtica as a string.
E.g.:

```
Export["testit.txt", "bla", "Text"];
Import["!dir" <> " testit* > dir.log", "Text"];
FilePrint["dir.log"]
```

--

Otherwise, I also had good results in the past using NETLink (not sure if WScript.shell 
still works on Windows7/8 or if one should use something else).
Emulating Run (RunThrough is not really needed  I think):

```
Run2[cmd_String] := Module[{shell},
    Switch[$OperatingSystem,
        "Windows",
            Needs["NETLink`"];
            shell = NETLink`CreateCOMObject["WScript.shell"];
            shell @ run[cmd,0,True],
        "Unix",
            Run @ cmd, 
        "MacOSX",
            Run @ cmd ] ];
```

Comment: It should. I just tried this on Windows 7:                 Run2["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"]    and in contrast to Run["start /min C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"] it seems smoother (no flicker)

Answer (score 3):

Can you run your application with input from a basic command window instead of the application console?  This might be the form of command you would need:

```
apame_win64 -input sphere_15000.inp
```

or simply

```
apame_win64 sphere_15000.inp
```

You can probably check the available switches by running `apame_win64 -help`

A multi-part command can be run from Mathematica, e.g.

```
Run["type c:\\temp\\test.txt"]
```

Alternatively, also returning output to the Mathematica session:

```
ReadList["!type c:\\temp\\test.txt", String]
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed here wanting to **run abaqus command line on windows**.

The solutions provided here **worked out for me** (Windows 7, Mathematica 9):

```
SetDirectory@path;
Run["start /min abaqus job=" <> fileName <> " interactive  ask_delete=OFF >> log.txt"]
```

(Here the abaqus option ask_delete=OFF overwrites an existing simulation results and the >> redirects all the output to a file)

I think, minimizing the window did not run in your case since the executable throws open that window. In that case, [this](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html) might be of some help